# How can I set up two virtual machines to connect via openssh?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, ssh

I have a host computer (a mac) running two Ubuntu systems as guest machines. I would like to set up an ssh connection between these two virtual machines.

Both guest machines are equipped with open-ssh server/client. I have given both guest machines "Bridge Mode" so they all have different IP addresses. Have internet connections. But when I try `ssh x.x.x.x`, it says connection is refused.

My understanding is that this can occur due to firewall settings?  Is there a way to solve this??

Is it even possible to accomplish ssh between two guest machines?? I don't see why not?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the IP config of both machines. In each one type `ip ad`, we need the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VirtualBox (you didn't specify), in the Network settings, select Host-only Adapter for both virtual machines.  They will be able to "see" each other.  (You will not be able to access outside the two machines, however).

Comment: There are several other possibilities beside using "host only".